# Getting "The content of element 'MethodOfPayment' is not complete", even though the element exists

Tags: xml, validation

I am having a problem validating an XML payload against a schema. The schema section causing the issue is summarised below. The element causing the problem is "MethodOfPayment/Cheque", which according to the schema documentation just needs to exist and should not contain any content.

```
<xsd:element name="MethodOfPayment" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element name="Cheque">
        <xsd:complexType/>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Account">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="...">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="...">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="...">
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Other">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="...">
            </xsd:element>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I am passing in the following simple structure:

```
<MethodOfPayment>
  <Cheque />
</MethodOfPayment>
```

But I am receiving the following validation error:

```
<ErrorMessage>
    <![CDATA[ Invalid Request!!! XML document failed validation.Please check XML request for valid data  
    cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'MethodOfPayment' is not complete. 
    One of '{"fake_namespace":Cheque, 
    "fake_namespace":Account, 
    "fake_namespace":Other}' is expected.]]>
</ErrorMessage>
```

I have confirmed that the "Account" and "Other" sections work fine, it is just the "Cheque" element. Any help with this would be great

Answer (score 0):

I eventually discovered that the above XML was not validating because the "Cheque" element was collapsed. Whenever I rehydrate the element, i.e. 
`<Cheque></Cheque>` as opposed to `<Cheque />` validation is successful.

Comment: If anyone else comes along this problem I had to output the empty tag as text in order to prevent it from collapsing, like so `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<Cheque></Cheque>]]></xsl:text>`